# Can't type spanish characters in some programs

Tags: keyboard, language

I have the keyboard layout set on spanish (I'm spanish).
In most programs I have no problems typing characters like á, ñ, è, é...

But there are some programs where I try to type 'á' for example, and the ´ key doesn't work. This happens in Telegram and IntelliJ IDEA. Is this an OS problem or do I have to download a 'spanish' version of this programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Telegram expects the wrong input method. You have two ways to fix it:

- Tell Telegram (and other Qt apps) to use xim
  Just set QT_IM_MODULE=xim before running it
- Run ibus
  Add ibus-daemon to your startup applications

  I don't know which one is better. There is a discussion in Telegram's github:
  https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/1041